# Where did the Slytherin house go during the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, slytherin

Now when the Slytherin students were able to escape, they were running and shouting, except for Goyle and Zabini who are grabbed by Malfoy.

Where did the House go afterwards? Did they fight the Death Eaters?

Answer (score 4):

Is this a movie or a book question?

Regardless, Professor McGonagall instructs the Slytherins to leave the Great Hall with Filch, but does not direct Filch to take the Slytherins to any particular place.

> ‘Thank you, Miss Parkinson,’ said Professor McGonagall in a clipped voice. ‘You will leave the Hall first with Mr Filch. If the rest of your house could follow.’
>   Harry heard the grinding of benches and then the sound of the Slytherins trooping out on the other side of the Hall.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter 31, *The Battle of Hogwarts* - Page 491 - Bloomsbury</sub>

In the movie, Professor McGonagall directs Filch to take the Slytherins to the dungeons. As the Slytherin dormitories are in the dungeons, it's unclear whether Filch is supposed to lock them up in their dorms, or if there is another dungeon the Slytherins are to be locked up in. The movie clip you provide obviously doesn't clarify which dungeon was meant.

Book: It's not stated.
Movie: One of the Hogwarts dungeons

Comment: Both movie and book

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts?noredirect=1&lq=1 you answered that 
The Slytherins came back and fought against Voldemort in the final battle, with Horace Slughorn leading the charge! In the clip that I send they were able to escape

Comment: I have answered for both the movie and the book. The Slytherins did come back and help with the fight, but that was some time after they were held back -- in a dungeon or another place in the castle, it's unclear. I'm not sure what your second comment has to do with the question at hand, which I have answered. :)

Comment: Slytherincess,the link that I send you is about Which Side Did the Slytherins Ultimately Fight For at the Battle of Hogwarts? Which you asked 6 years ago. Since JK Rowling said that they come back and fought Voldemort and the death eaters ,then why is it not included in the book.

Comment: Well, not being the author, I wouldn't know why anything was or wasn't included in the book. All I can tell you is J.K. Rowling did not specify where the Slytherins were banished *to* when Filch led them from the Great Hall. I mean, that's the answer to your question. I don't know what else to say. :)