# Who are the reinforcements led by Slughorn?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, slytherin

Slughorn goes to Hogsmade for collecting reinforcements.

[According to an answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Harry-Potter-creative-franchise-Were-there-any-Slytherin-students-defending-Hogwarts), JK Rowling said in an interview last January 2008 that

> the group who followed Slughorn from Hogsmeade to Hogwarts to fight for the school were mainly Slytherins and their families, because Slytherins are brave in a *practical* way and so they went home first and collected reinforcements before joining the fight. She says that this was one of her favourite scenes in the book so it’s unlikely this is an ex post facto rationalisation, But she forgot to specify that they were Slytherins in the book.

In the book they were no Slytherins who fought. Since she is the author, is this true? We don't know if those reinforcements are Slytherin because it's not in the books nor in the movie.

Comment: As she is the author, how could it not be true?

Comment: Word of God is canon with highest priority and what's your question exactly? Do you want us to verify author's words?

Comment: Blackwood,since it is not mentioned in the book. JKR only mentioned in her interview.

Comment: A duplicate of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts?

Comment: It does seem like you are trying to ask the same question multiple times. Perhaps you could try editing the previous question to make it not duplicate?

Comment: In any case, whether you choose to view Rowling's words on the matter as authoritative is up to you. You may feel that the canonical version of the series is what Rowling declares, or what she published, or what she submitted to the editors, or what she scribbled on napkins.

Comment: Adamant, I'm researching about these questions. Because I need to know if slytherin fight during the battle of hogwarts

Comment: That question has already been answered, though.

Comment: Is it yes or no,lol

Comment: She told us later that Dumbledore was gay. It wasn't in the book, but that doesn't mean it isn't 'true'. When I write, I may know that the shawl my character wears is grey, but that doesn't mean the reader knows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Slytherins.

It's obviously true seeing as she's the author. Here is the interview as quoted from Slytherincess' [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts).

> JN: And how much is it that being sorted into Slytherin is, you know, sorted into good guys and bad guys here?
>
> JKR: Well, they’re not all bad, that would- I know I’ve said this before, (JN: Yeah, I remember.) and I think I said it to Emerson [Spartz - Mugglenet.com], they are not all bad, and, well, far from it. As we know, at the end, they may have (laughs) a slightly more highly developed sense of self-preservation then other people because…
>
> SU: Yeah, right.
>
> JN: Yeah.
>
> JKR: **A part of the final battle that made me smile was Slughorn galloping back with Slytherins**, (SU: Yes!) (JN: laughs) but they’d gone off to get reinforcements first, you know what I’m saying? But yes, they came back, they came back to fight, so I mean- but I’m sure that many people would say “Well, that’s common sense, isn’t it? Isn’t that smart, to get out, get more people and come back with them?”

Comment: Is it in the movie? Sorry I can't recall the movie because it was released 6 years ago. But if it in the movie what scene it is?

Comment: Never happened in the books nor the movie(s).

Comment: Then why is it not in the book nor the movie? Since jk rowling said that the reinforcements are slytherins

Comment: **Who knows.** My guess would be that: JK Rowling only thought about that after writing the book. Probably wanted to redeem the 'bad' prejudice against the Slytherins.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.So basically they fought against voldemort.But it was off screen

Comment: Yep, that's what happened. Also, I want to point out something: I noticed that you have **never** accepted any kind of answer to your question(s). You can click the green arrow  located below the downvote button to 'accept' an answer. This helps users viewing your question see the recommended answer on the top of the list.

Comment: In fact slytherin isn't evil. Perhaps in the movie and in the book they were fighting when they are called reinforcements. But it was off screen in both book and movie.