# Who was Phineas Nigellus Black talking about?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification, slytherin

> "And let it be known that Slytherin House played its part! Let our contribution not be forgotten!"
>   <sub><sup>**— Phineas Nigellus, following the Battle of Hogwarts and Voldemort's death (*Deathly Hallows* - Page 747 US Hardcover)**</sup></sub>

I know that this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7351/70135) says that *"Phineas was talking about Snape"*.  I disagreed with this answer. The [accepted answer of this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts/%20%22question) is saying that Slytherins were reinforcements led by Slughorn. Now forgive me, I doubt these two [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts/%22answers). Nevertheless, who was **Phineas Nigellus Black talking about**? Was it **Snape**, **Slughorn** or the **Slytherins** who were reinforcements?

Comment: He was obviously talking about the Slytherin students led by Slughorn. Why do you disagree with the other answers?

Comment: But Kevin said that Phineas was talking about snape.Which i disagree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Side Did the Slytherins Ultimately Fight For at the Battle of Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/which-side-did-the-slytherins-ultimately-fight-for-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts)

Comment: Might be worth giving some context (what book in the series, and where in the plot this is) etc.

Comment: Phineas certainly knew about Snape's part (almost all conversations between Snape and Dumbledore took place in the latter's office). He also probably knew about Slughorn and the Slytherins if he was watching the battle from other portraits. Isn't it logical to conclude he was talking about all of them? Also since Snape's part was more emphasised than anything else, how could he not be referring to him?

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. The other question cites Black's quotation but isn't about it.

Comment: The Dark lord yep

Comment: Elrond, the thing is I disagreed that phineas is talking about snape

Comment: I don't see how this can be resolved except from a direct quote from JKR stating what Black was refering. It seems to me Black was saying literally what he said: that Slytheryn House (as a whole: Snape, Slughorn and the fighters) contributed to the fall of Voldemor, but how do we expect to resolve this without opinion based answers?

Comment: @Ram I always thought he was simply talking about Slytherin House as a whole, too.

Comment: Ram,who are those fighters that are you talking about

Comment: Maybe it's also about Regulus...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It seems likely that he was referring to Slytherin House in general.**

The members of Slytherin House are commonly most associated with dark magic, and the Dark Lord himself was a Slytherin. Slytherin may get part of the blame for the rise of the Dark Lord, and it's done nothing to help their reputation. It seems likely that Phineas Nigellus Black is saying he wants the part Slytherin House and its members made to the defeat of the Dark Lord not to be forgotten, and to be remembered in history as much as the members of other Houses would be, and not only be remembered for being the House of the Dark Lord and many of the Death Eaters.

Comment: I like your answer, but do you have any quotes from the book or WoG to back this up?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach The only relevant quote that I think exists is the one already included in the question, what he said wasn't significant enough to be mentioned again in the book. I've checked, and his statement isn't mentioned again after he makes it. There probably aren't any interviews that mention it either, but I can't say so definitively.

Comment: Bellatrix, How did you say that " It seems likely that Phineas Nigellus Black is saying he wants the part Slytherin House and its members made to the defeat of the Dark Lord not to be forgotten". What contribution did the slytherins do? Remember that this is during the battle of hogwarts,when phineas talks to harry.

Comment: @Legolas Draco: After the battle.

Comment: Chirlu, thanks. But who is phineas talking about?

Comment: @LegolasDraco I think he's just talking about the members of Slytherin House in general, although he may have had more specific individuals in mind (like Snape, Slughorn, the Slytherin students Slughorn led as reinforcements - or even someone else, which is unlikely but possible) although unfortunately, there's no more information available other than the quote itself. It could also be possible that he wants to ensure that his House gets credit, but doesn't have any specific reason why, other than House pride.

Answer (score 0):

I think he had multiple people he refered to. He liked Snape and knew the truth being in Dumbledores office. Also Malfoys (relatives) , his great great grandson regulus, Slughorns reinforcements etc. He wanted people to remember slytherin were not just death eaters but also helped.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to be essentially what the existing answer states; is there anything you could add, or additional references, that aren't included in that answer?